# Remove action event from component

Tags: codenameone

In the GUI Designer I accidentally clicked on the `Action Event` button for a component I don't want to have a click event.  Now I can't figure out how to get rid of it.  Leaving the generated override method blank will prevent the click from triggering anything, but I don't even want the component (a `List`) to be clickable, just the list items themselves.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the method from the state machine and save. It will remove it as if you never clicked that action event button.

Comment: Shai, I tried deleting the method in `StateMachine` and in `StateMachineBase` even though it seemed futile even as I did it, yet the `List` in its entirety remains clickable.  Then I went into the GUI Designer, deleted the component, saved, and added a new one and gave it the same name.  Miraculously, when I opened the Events tab, Action Even and List Model were both bold.  So I deleted again and added a new `List` with a different name.  Same result.  What's going on here?  When I run it in the simulator the `List` is still clickable.

Comment: And one more thing, it seems sometimes that it takes quite a while for the `StateMachine` class to update after I save changes to the GUI.  Is there some way to manually 'refresh' `StateMachine`?

Comment: Okay, I think deleting the method did remove the Action Event, as you said, but I still see it as an override option in the `StateMachine`.  What does that mean?  And if I click on the list in the simulator, the whole component takes on its 'pressed' style, not the individual item clicked.  What does this mean?

Comment: Never edit statemachine base... The List has selected style when you click it. I assume you use a blank theme which is a problem in its own. I suggest filing separate questions if you are still confused or using the discussion forum where moderation is less of an issue.